# Sinatra: What's the correct way to serve a plain old file?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

This works, but it was a stab in the dark. I know little Ruby.

What's the accepted way to serve a plain old file for a given resource?

```
get '/xyz' do
    File.read 'abc.html'
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use `set :public` to specify the directory for your static files.  Then, you can serve the file using `send_file()` for example:

```
    get '/static_file' do
      send_file('my_static_file')
   end
```

Comment: The configuration keyword was [changed](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130--2011-09-30) from `:public` to `:public_folder` in version 1.3.0.

Answer (score 4):

Serve it out of the ./public directory.  See the [Static Files](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) section of the README and the [:static and :public configuration options](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html).

Comment: How would it know to map /xyz to abc.html with :static? Is File.read the right way to output a named file?

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood.  If you configure a :public and want abc.html than point at http://webserver/abc.html and sinatra won't route it'll just serve the html.  If you want to custom route and serve a static file, I think nstehr has got it.  Of course you could also just name your abc.html to xyz (or symlin) in your public directory, but I still think I like nstehr's way.