# RMagick & Sinatra: send picture to view without storing

Tags: sinatra, image, rmagick

Currently I am writing a Sinatra app that gets some pictures from user and returns a new picture.

There's part of haml form:

```
  %input{type:'file', name:'user_image'}
```

And there's a code from handler: (montage is another picture)

```
  source_userpic = params[:user_image][:tempfile]
  blob = File.open(source_userpic).read
  userpic = ImageList.new
  userpic.from_blob(blob)
  resized_img = userpic.scale(montage.columns,
                              montage.rows)
  resized_img.opacity = MaxRGB/3
```

Then two images are "layered" with composite and stored (don't need)

```
  final_picture = ImageList.new
  final_picture << montage.composite(resized_img, 0, 0, OverCompositeOp)


  final_picture.write("./public/uploads/#{DateTime.now}.jpg" # dirty (for example)
```

Next, I need to show a final_picture with ajax. There are two obvious problems: first, I don't need to save a final_picture - it's just preview, second, I must write code to avoid filenames conflicts...

How to send a final_picture to view? to_blob method? But what's next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved that by using the data URI scheme.

```
require 'base64'

final_picture.format = "jpeg" # whatever
# Using a to_blob method to create a direct-to-memory version of the image.
# Then encode it to base64 string
data_uri = Base64.encode64(final_picture.to_blob).gsub(/\n/, "") 
@image_tag = '<img alt="preview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,%s">' % data_uri

haml:'pages/preview'
```

Then display a picture by

```
= @image_tag
```

Not sure if it's best solution

Comment: That won't avoid filename conflicts, if you get another file with the same name and encode the name in base 64 it will produce the same output. Base 64 is an _encoding_ and as such is **deterministic**.

Comment: He's not creating a file with the name encoded in base64, he is encoding the image content in base64 and using an html tag that accepts the image in that format, thus sidestepping any file name issues altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html), that should take care of file name conflicts for you.

Then you could use the technique from [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203600/sinatra-whats-the-correct-way-to-serve-a-plain-old-file), using [send_file](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/Sinatra/Helpers#send_file-instance_method) to send the tempfile.

You have to remember that the tempfile won't persist, so you have to be careful to manage that persistence if you are using different requests and responses to serve the file.

Comment: Thanks for answer! It might help in some cases.